# Where do packages' relative paths begin?

Tags: java, relative-path

After a long, arduous task of loading images using `getResourceAsStream`, I decided to organize all of my source code into packages within my src folder.

Since then, my original method of retrieving files no longer works.

Here is the original class I made:

```
package main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ResourceLoader {

    public static BufferedImage getImage(String uri) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = null; 

        image = ImageIO.read(ResourceLoader.class.getResource(uri));

        return image;

    }

}
```

As mentioned previously, this worked 100% fine when entering the path:

```
"imgs/anims/testimage.png"
```

Worked perfectly fine with this. imgs is a folder within the source folder res.

Comment: *I decided to organize all of my source code into packages within my src folder* Okay. Well put everything back. Or show us what you did.

Comment: how do you "build"/compile?

Comment: ..but to your very question: "At the root of the class path!"

Comment: @EllioFrisch I put them in there to organize the code, so I'm not going to put them back. I put objects relating to certain "parent" objects in the same folder. For example, I have a class called Projectile. I put that class, and everything that extends it in the same folder.

Comment: @xerx593 I'm extremely confused by what your first comment is asking. Are you asking literally? And I get that it's at the root of the class path. I'm asking what that is. It's clearly either not my project folder or I'm using the wrong kind of folder to store my resources

Comment: ..your very = title question "Where do packages relative paths begin?"  ... and then my question (1st. comment) is relevant/literally! (do you use an IDE or a "build tool" (ant, maven, gradle, manymanymore)?).. and I m pointing into the direction: that someone has to take care of the images to be available..on class path!

Comment: I use Eclipse's build tool. And I get that, but why would placing java files into packages within my src folder change the classpath? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: did you move `ResourceLoader` from `src/` to `src/main`??!? x-) (-> move `res/imgs` to `res/main/imgs` OR use `/imgs...` instead!)

Comment: Yes, I moved resource loader to src/main. I don't have a res/main/imgs. How does adding main to the res path make a major difference? Adding a slash before imgs worked, by the way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We found your issue:

You used to load all of your images *relatively* to `ResourceLoader` which was located in the root package (discouraged!, and good that you refactored).

But now (You moved `ResourceLoader` from `/` to `/main`, and) all of your URIs point into "nirvana", since there are no `imgs/...` relatively to `/main`.

---

Solution:

1. #### refactor `/imgs` to `/main/imgs` according to ResourceLoader

   Move `imgs` to `main/imgs`. (if `main` is (surely!) not there, *please create it*, this solution requires no code/uri adjustments.)
2. #### alternatively use absolute addressing

   Refer to (*all of*) your images as `/imgs/...` (with a trailing slash character (`/`)).
3. #### alternatively refactor ResourceLoader back to /.

   Also no further code/uri adjustments needed.

Comment: **or**, switch to maven and use a standard package layout ([resource directory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)).

Comment: ..the key is that he moved ResourceLoader ...didn't move imgs ...but still refers (relatively!) to "imgs/" :)